# Sending Email to Segmented List is excluding contacts without adding excluded list

Tags: exm

When trying to send email campaign using segmented list, some contacts are excluded however I am not adding any excluded list.

Is there a way to view a list of excluded contacts?

Comment: Which Sitecore version? If you check your EXM root, is there any Global Opt Out list selected on that item?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, yes I checked it but not contacts are added to this list